# observeValueForKeyPath not called for property holding C++ object?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I've got a weird problem.

My class declares a property that just keeps a pointer to a C++ object around:

`@property (assign) CPPObject *representedObject;`

In the `init` of that Obj-C class I'm then registering the class itself as observer to get notified when somebody assign something to my property (yeah, I could write a custom setter.... anywho!).

```
   [self addObserver:self
          forKeyPath:@"representedObject"
             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
             context:nil];
```

Dumping `observationInfo` after registering as an observer looks OK - should have been registered.

However my `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method is never called.

Looking through related StackOverflow topics didn't bring me any closer to resolving this issue..
The property is properly set via setting `object.representedObject`, etc.

**Any clues** what could be fishy here..?
Bad idea to register for `self` in the `init` method..?

**Edit #1**

When using a manual setter instead of the synthesized one that setter *is being called*.

Comment: Why would you add an observer for self if you could just override representedObject's setter and getter?

Answer (score 1):

If your observations aren't getting called at all, I would first suspect that the synthesized accessor isn't being called, possibly because someone is accessing the ivars directly, which you shouldn't do for exactly this reason. Try implementing a custom setter (it can just do a normal assignment) and make sure it's being called.

---

EDIT: My next test would be to make sure that you've named your observation method correctly. I don't know if this is Mac or iOS; on Mac, incorrectly naming the observation method wouldn't crash the app. On iOS it would crash unless you happened to have it implemented somewhere else (superclass, or implemented somewhere else in your implementation).

Personally, I'd probably pull out a minimal test case into a new project, and see if you can reproduce it in a single file. I'm sure when you're done it's going to be something silly. Badly named method. Two different instances of the same class (and you're looking at the wrong one). Methods running in an order that you don't expect. Something like that.

Comment: That's the funny bit - the manual setter is being called..   
Didn't change any other part of the code, i.e. not the bit setting the properties! Just weird.

Comment: Don't you need to call `[self will/didChangeValueFor:@"representedObject"]` around the assignment in the setter?

Comment: No. You should not call these. They are injected automatically by KVO. That's half the point of KVO. KVO is one of the few magical parts of pre-ARC Cocoa. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the `keyword` dynamic in order to achieve KVO as described in Apple's documentation [KVO Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_5)

Comment: This is Objective-C, not Swift.